# DeepLearningの学習データ(jpeg、raw)と組み込みシステムについて

Tags: アルゴリズム, 機械学習

私は画像を使ったディープラーニングについて勉強しています。
今回疑問があり皆様の意見を聞きたく投稿しました。

一般的にWebの画像認識に使用する学習データは容量を少なくする為、jpeg画像が多いと思います。
しかし、組み込みシステムで使用するカメラ画像は圧縮せずにraw形式の画像をメモリに保存し認識処理すると思います。

ここで、Web上の学習モデル(jpeg)を使用した場合、組み込みシステムと画像の形式が異なるため、認識に差はでないのでしょうか。raw画像の方が情報量が多く、jpeg画像は圧縮するため、情報量が少ない為、疑問に思いました。

皆様の解答よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

「情報量が多い・少ない」とは、どういう意味でしょうか。JPEGだろうがRAWだろうが、学習・推論するときには、ピクセル数×色深度の情報量になりますが？

もちろん、JPEGは不可逆圧縮ですので、RAWのままの画像とは異なります。これは、「情報量の多少」ではなく、そもそもの「情報」が異なります。情報の、量ではなく質が落ちています。プーリングのカーネルサイズを大きくすることで、ある程度吸収できるようです。（JPEGで学習、Bitmapで推論をしましたが、満足できる精度が出ました。もちろん、私のケースではうまくいきましたが、全部のケースでうまくいくとは限りません。そもそも、JPEGの圧縮率が不明ですし。）

Comment: +1。ただし、以下のことを思いました: 質問者さんは、専門用語としての[情報量](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%83%85%E5%A0%B1%E9%87%8F)のイメージで言葉を使われたのかもしれません。Wikipedia の [JPEG のページ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#%E7%AC%A6%E5%8F%B7%E5%8C%96%E6%96%B9%E5%BC%8F)に書かれているように、この意味だと JPEG の情報量は RAW より少なくなることがあります。この意味の「情報量」は、だいたい Q71.MSK さんの言葉でいうところの「情報の質」と同じで、データのサイズという意味ではないです。

Comment: JPEG圧縮はブロックに分割、離散コサイン変換をするので変化がなだらかになる、ということでしょうか。ウチでは、私はコード担当で、理論は他の人なのですが、理論の人は「JPEG 圧縮の方が学習には向いている」と言っていました、ということを付け加えておきます。

Comment: いえ、離散コサイン変換までは RAW と理論上は情報量が変わらないはずですが、その後[量子化](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%87%8F%E5%AD%90%E5%8C%96)を行うところで情報量が落ちます。